# Error on setOnClickListner and addPreferencesFromResource

Tags: android, onclick, android-preferences

Please help me about these errors. I don't know what the problem is.

Errors are in "**addPreferencesFromResource**" and "**setOnclicklistner**":

"The method addPreferencesFromResource(int) is undefined for the type..."

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_pref);
```

and

```
1-"The method setOnClickListener(view.setOnClickListener) in the type view is not applicable for the arguments (newDialogInterface.OnClickListner(){})"  

2-"The type new Dialoginterface.OnClickListner(){} must be implement the inherited abstract method Dialoginterface.OnClickListner.OnClick(DialogInterface, Int)" 



 b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 public void onClick(View arg0) {
 startActivity(new Intent(main.this, Settings.class));  

    }
});
```

Comment: You missed the @Override tag before your onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct OnClickListeners, one for Views and one for Dialogs. You are apparently already implementing the Dialog one somewhere else, so it's getting confused, try this:

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
     startActivity(new Intent(main.this, Settings.class));  
   }
});
```